# Audio tag doesn't run the music

Tags: css, html

I have the audio file saved in a file along with the .html file.  For some reason the music player or interface appears on my screen however nothing plays.  I have looked at tutorials and online websites and have done nothing different.  What am I doing wrong?

```
    <audio controls>

     <source src="Weightless.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
      </audio>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have enough "reputation" to comment, so sorry for the "answer". Just to help troubleshoot on your end and on ours, try referencing the absolute source:

```
<source src="http://www.yoursite.com/Weightless.mp3" type="audio.mpeg">
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to trigger the tag by javascript or do . That will automatically set the trigger to space.